# Python random choice math task (code integer message)

Tags: python, random

I have the following code:

```
import random
import operator

operators={"+":operator.add,
           "-":operator.sub,
           "X":operator.mul}

name = input(" What is Your Name ? :")
score = 0
counter = 1

for question in range(0,10):
    num1 = random.randint(1,13)
    num2 = random.randint(1,13)
    ranop = random.choice(operators)
    answer = operators.get(ranop,num1,num2)#operator searches in operators(DICTIONARY) for random operator and then use num1 and num2 to create a question
    print("{0} {1} {2}=".format(num1,ranop,num2))
    if guess==answer:
          print("✔")
    else:
        print("✘,The answer was {0}".format(answer))
print ("{0}, You Finished! You got {1}/10".format(name.title(),score))
```

I can't find why the following error occurs:

```
What is Your Name ? :s
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "substr.py", line 15, in <module>
    ranop = random.choice(operators)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/random.py", line 254, in choice
    return seq[i]
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: If you really have an issue, please take time to edit your question and to point out 1-what is your problem, 2-what do you want to achieve, 3-what are you currently doing to try to reach that goal.

Comment: problem is the ranop line ive tried rewriting checking websites but still cant find the solution. i want a code to ask 10 randomly selected questions using +-and* operators but currently stopped cause of unknown bug...

Comment: Please *edit your question* to explain what's going wrong.  Are you getting a traceback?  If so, please include that traceback in the question.  Are you getting wrong results?  If so, show the results you are getting and say what you expected instead.

Comment: edited now tracekback in expecting random questions to be listed 1 t a time after answer is inserted

Answer (score 2):

[`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) requires a [sequence type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange), like `tuple` or `list`.  Changing `random.choice(operators)` to `random.choice(list(operators))` should fix this specific issue, but I still have no idea what you're attempting to do with this code.

Comment: It will fail on the very next line though, because `operators.get(ranop,num1,num2)` is not legal; `dict.get` takes at most two arguments; the key to get, and the default value if the key is not found. I suspect the OP meant to do: `operators.get(ranop)(num1,num2)` (though using `.get` is silly when the key was chosen from the `dict`, so `operators[ranop](num1,num2)` would work much more succinctly/efficiently).

Comment: @ShadowRanger I also don't know where `guess` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following errors:

```
ranop = random.choice(operators) # choice takes a sequence, not a dictionary.
answer = operators.get(ranop,num1,num2)
# In your case, get takes a single argument.  It returns a function, which you apply to the numbers.
guess == answer # You never define guess.
```

It should now run, but you probably want to increment `score` at some point.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help running better on way to fixing. Sorry for the bad post new here and don't find python the easiest. not that great at it either.